# OSM query in R gives error message

Tags: r

I want these query:

```
osmmap<-get_map(location=c(-123.9, 36.85,-121.58, 38.75),maptype="coner-lite",source="stamen")
```

But I got this error message

```
Error in `get_map()`:
! Invalid stamen `maptype`, see `get_stamenmap()`.
Backtrace:
 1. ggmap::get_map(...)
 Error in get_map(location = c(-123.9, 36.85, -121.58, 38.75), :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: maptype="coner-lite" should be "toner-lite". The error message was quite clear that the maptype was invalid.